# Transparent PNG with alpha channel parts shows with ugly border

Tags: vb.net, image, gdi

Maybe someone out there can help, I am trying to display a transparent PNG in a form as a splash screen. The code on the form is:

```
Sub Form_Paint(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
  Dim r As New Rectangle(0, 0, 728, 462)
  Dim newBitmap As Bitmap
  newBitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("Logo.png")
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(newBitmap, r)
end sub
```

The resulting image shows with an ugly 'feathered' border. See here:
[image]

The image is a 32bit ARGB that has been given transparency on the edges. This is the PNG embedded in a web page:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of the border?

Comment: That is not a code problem but a design one. Wrong place.

Comment: don't think so, check the edit above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
```

See also this:
[How to draw smooth images with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566245/how-to-draw-smooth-images-with-c)

Anyway, as another user noted, the issue is with the image which was created without any anti-aliasing. The above snippet will alleviate the problem but the best option is to adjust the image.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it's the image, see my edit above for how it looks when embedded in a web page. Also the snippet made no difference.

Comment: I've been checking MSDN and the problem lies in the Image Class (base class of Bitmap). I found here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx) the following:

The Image class does not support alpha transparency in bitmaps. To enable alpha transparency, use PNG images with 32 bits per pixel.

Comment: Can you debug bmp.PixelFormat?

Comment: I tried SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True), then making the background transparent but it just shows the background as solid beige. I can get rid of that beige by making the transparency key to be "systemcolors.control" but it still has the border.

Comment: Thanks for your help dna2, but I am cutting my losses. Just going to put a background in the image, get rid of all the transparent parts.