# .NET ImageList to PictureBox draws image jagged

Tags: .net, image, graphics, picturebox

I am trying to paint an image from an imagelist to a picturebox on demand, not in the OnPaint event.

I am using

```
 Me.picUserImage.Image = Me.ILUserIcons.Images(sGUID)
```

This works fine, but the image looks jagged.

Usually (when I am using OnPaint) I use the following code:

```
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.ilUsers.Images(iImageIndex), nRect)
```

This works fine. But I am unable to set this smoothing mode in my on-demand sub.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you resizing that image with the nRect?  Screen shot would help, the before and after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw smooth images with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566245/how-to-draw-smooth-images-with-c)

Comment: But your audience doesn't know that.  Try `nRect.Location` instead of just `nRect`.

Comment: An ImageList is not an appropriate image collection object.  Not setting its ImageSize and ColorDepth properties to sufficiently large values is the next standard mistake.  Use a List(Of Image) instead.